# Background not filling entire screen in scrollview android

Tags: android, xml, background, fullscreen

I'm developing an app and I need to fill the entire screen with a background, this view contains a scrollview. The problem is that the background is not covering the entire screen, it has a white stripe at the bottom, like the image below.

[image]

I have already tried many options of scaleType, like fitXY, centerInside, etc. none of them worked out.
My XML is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/signup_background" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="40dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view_photo"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_name"
                style="@style/BaseEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/name_icon"
                android:hint="@string/field_name"
                android:inputType="textCapWords" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_email"
                style="@style/BaseEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email_icon"
                android:hint="@string/field_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_password"
                style="@style/BaseEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
                android:hint="@string/field_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_confirm_password"
                style="@style/BaseEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
                android:hint="@string/field_confirm_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <com.jacksonueda.reachalert.Utils.LoadingButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_up" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, what I needed to do was to put a RelativeLayout as parent of the ScrollView, like below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/signup_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="40dp">

            ...

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to give background to `ConstraintLayout` with width `wrap_content`. also set your height for both `ScrollView` and ConstraintLayout `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

In constraint layout you have to specify constraint. You don't have specified constraint in ImageView

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/signup_background" />
```

Replace it with

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/signup_background"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **`RelativeLayout`** instead of `ConstraintLayout` in your xml. Relative Layout is best for overlapping two elements of xml.